# How can I inspect a SearchRequestObject to what its query, filter, and aggs parameters are?

Tags: java, json, scala, elasticsearch

I'm developing an application based upon Elasticsearch.

I need to be able to to construct a `SearchRequestBuilder` object from a JSON string. I can do that ok using the `setSource` method and passing a full JSON query object as parameter. So far so good.

An example: (Obs.: I'm using the Java API from Scala).

```
var builder = client.java.prepareSearch("logindex*")
   .setSource("""
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": ":mimeType:text\\/html"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "datetime": {
            "gte": "2014-09-18T00:56:00",
            "lte": "2014-09-29T00:56:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}""")
```

But I also really need to be able to "inspect" the object created in that manner and see what its **query** is, for example (so I can make sure that the user isn't trying to access something he/she shouldn't be and so on). Ideally I would like to have methods like `getQueryBuilder` and the like.

```
// i know I can manipulate the previously created object like this:
builder.addAggregation(...)
// but can I also perhaps ask questions to the object?
// for instance
var query = builder.getQueryBuilder //or something like this
// and then find out what type of query it is and maybe turn it into a filtered query
// so I can limit what the users can view.
```

I was hopeful that `SearchRequestBuilder#internalBuilder` could be what I was looking for but I couldn't get any useful info from it.

I hope that I managed to get my point across and that I made myself understood.

Answer (score 1):

I think that better way of doing this is to simply parse and validate/manipualate JSON before setting it as the source. There ale plenty of scala JSON parsing libraries. I presonally like [scala4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) as it has nice DSL and it is well documented. It also has [diffing](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#merging--diffing) feature which may be especially useful in your case.